# This request is not supported in the specified qbXML version

Tags: vb.net, qbxml

I am using VB.NET 2008, with QBFC 12.  When I try to get a Payroll Summary Report, I get an error.

This request is not supported in the specified qbXML version.

The error happens on the following line of code:

```
    Dim PayrollSummaryReportQueryRq As IPayrollSummaryReportQuery
    PayrollSummaryReportQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendPayrollSummaryReportQueryRq()
```

I copied this code directly from the OSR for the SDK.  I have no idea why this won't work.  The OSR says that the request has been available since SDK V3.  As best I can see, it should be working.  Why not?

Comment: Post the QBXML being generated.

Comment: How do I collect the XML?  It is auto-generated by the QBFC.